# onCreateView not called for tabs in actionbar TabsAdapter for second time tab selected?

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, adapter

I have a tabbed application built with fragments and ActionBarSherlock. I have 3 tabs, with 3 ListFragment's Here's what's happening.

When I select any tab, the onCreate method for the associated fragment is called as expected at first time but not at second. The problem is that the onCreate method is called for the next adjacent tab but not selected tab.

Click on tab2 and onCreate of tab3 is called but not tab2.

Actually my requirement is, when i change some data in tab1 means fragment1. those changes are not effected in fragment2, when i select tab2 (fragment2) it means fragment2 onCreate() was not calling. why it's not refreshing the fragment properly. this is the adapter i am using.

```
private class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, ActionBar.TabListener {

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ActionBar actionBar, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = actionBar;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, int tabId) {
        mTabs.add(clss.getName());
        mTabsId.add(tabId);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab.setTabListener(this));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Integer getIdForPosition(int position) {
        if (position >= 0 && position < mTabsId.size()) {
            return mTabsId.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, mTabs.get(position), new Bundle());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.i(TAG, "*******tab selected*******" +tab);
        clearDetails();
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != tab.getPosition()) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        if (mCurrentPosition == position) {          
        }
        mNextPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {      
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {          
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {          
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html):

> The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory,
>   though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible.

This means that your fragments that are not visible to the user are still being kept in memory, so their onCreate methods won't be called when they're redisplayed. You can force them to be kicked out of memory when you switch pages by setting the ViewPager's [offscreen page limit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) to 0.

A better way might be to use some sort of external data model shared between your Fragments and then use your onPageSelected method to tell the Fragment to update itself based on the data model when brought into view.

Comment: i set this parameter to my ViewPager mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0); even though it's not working for me.

Comment: Then you may need to use an event handler to force those fragments to update themselves when brought into view. Alternatively, you could force a completely new instance of the fragment to be created each time in your onTabSelected event handler.

Comment: already i am doing like this @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.i(TAG, "*******tab selected*******" +tab);
        clearDetails();
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != tab.getPosition()) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), true);
        }
    } in onTabSelected() look at my code, what i have to do beyond this to do work properly..

Comment: is there any solution to solve this issue. if it has tell me.

Comment: I would really go with my suggestion to use some shared data model object. It would simply hold all the data that you needed to display in your fragments and then you can set up a method in each of your fragments to take the updated data model object and populate the views with the new information, then call this method on the newly displayed fragment whenever onPageSelected gets triggered.

Comment: This doesn't work - you can't set the offscreen page limit to 0.  If you do, you'll see this in the logs: W/ViewPager(32477): Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1.

Answer (score 1):

when you are on a **Tab:(n)**, only **Tab:(n-1)** and **Tab:(n+1)** will be alive in the memory, for memory usage optimization. Rest all Tabs will be destroyed, thats the reason why when you come back to the first Tab, its `onCreateView` is being called again.

Actually **Tab:1**'s `onCreateView` will be called even if you click **Tab:2** because its the neighbourhood Tab.

**One solution i got is:**

change the `OffscreenPageLimit` of the `ViewPager`. Its default value is `1`

Try changing it to `0`. Should work.But in case if it didn't

**Use the Call backs**

```
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
```